# Get bootstrap navbar full-width with centered text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating my new website and I would like to set my navbar full-width with my centered text.
All is fine, but I don't overcome to set full-width.

```css
body {
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #C44632;
}

#content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>

    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Matériel <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Optiques</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monture</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Capteurs Photo</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessoires</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Photographies <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Planétaire</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ciel Profond</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Autres</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Article</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Données Météo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qui suis-je ?</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

What is missing in order to get full-width navbar ?

Comment: Put your nav outside "container" and thats it

Comment: Ok thank you it works :)

Comment: It is because the nav bar fits with the container size Put your navbar outside of container div. it will be fine

Comment: @Deadpool np :) It is the easiest solution I think :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is fine, You just need to put your `<div class="container">` inside `<nav>`.

Try this:

```css
body {
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}

.navbar-nav {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a {
    color : #C44632;
}

#content {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Matériel <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Optiques</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Monture</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Capteurs Photo</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Accessoires</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Photographies <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Planétaire</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ciel Profond</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Autres</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Article</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Données Météo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Qui suis-je ?</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Glad to help you mate:). Accept as answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

**Change :**

```
<div class="container">
```

**To:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

**and in css:**

```
.container-fluid {
   padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ehsan :)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap `.container` has fixed width (1170px) for medium devices, you need to make it `100%`;

PS: Adding a custom class to override bootstrap's css is good practice.

```
.custom-container{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
}

.custom-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1B1B1B;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #C44632;
}

#content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
  .custom-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>

<div class="container custom-container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Matériel <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Optiques</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monture</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Capteurs Photo</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessoires</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Photographies <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Planétaire</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ciel Profond</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Autres</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Article</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Données Météo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Qui suis-je ?</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It was easy , happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to put your `<nav>` outside `<div class="container">` because `<div class="container">` has it's own styling(padding)